# Given eigenvectors, what is the set of eigenvalues that makes the matrix have specific coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

I have a $\mathbb{F}_2^{n\times n}$ matrix $P$ = $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_0 \\
1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -c_1 \\
0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & -c_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -c_{n-1}
 \end{bmatrix} $ that has characteristic polynomial $p(x) = x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 x + c_0$ such as roots of $p(x)$ are primitive $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ elements.

I can write $P = QDQ^{-1}$ where $Q$ is the basis of eigenvectors and $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

I am looking for the set of matrices $P' = QD'Q^{-1} $such that $ D'$  is diagonal, its coefficients are primitive $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^*$ elements, and P' elements are all ones or zeroes

Is P the only one in this set ? If not,

a) can I construct such $P'$ matrix ?

b) How many such $P'$ matrices exist ?

c) Can I sample a random matrix from the set of all $P'$ ?

Any answer that can help me to have a better understanding of the subject is welcome